# How to discover whether magic SysRq key is enabled, and what keys invoke it?

Tags: linux, magic-sysrq

How can I know what keys will invoke the magic SysRq key? Provided I am in front of a Linux machine which is not frozen (yet). I need something easier than trying all common combinations of magic SysRq key to discover if it's working.

Comment: Note that, at least for me, I have to **hold** the `Alt` key, release the `SysRq` (`PrintScreen`) key, and then press the 3rd key while still holding `Alt`, in order for it to work properly...

Answer (score 19):

The magic SysRq key itself is <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>SysRq</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Print Screen</kbd> on PCs, which is in turn combined with a third key (letter), indicating some specific action.

The short version is that, at a console, <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>SysRq</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> will display the available shortcuts (thanks to [Josip Rodin](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/103306/josip-rodin) for pointing that out).

The magic SysRq key, if enabled, is controlled by `/proc/sys/kernel/sysrq`; you can determine if it's enabled and what functions are allowed by running

```
cat /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq
```

If this complains that there's no such file or directory, then magic SysRq isn't enabled at all. Otherwise it will show a number which determines the available functions:

- 0: disable SysRq completely
- 1: enable all functions
- any other value is a bitmask of allowed functions:

  - 2: control console logging level
  - 4: control keyboard
  - 8: process debug dumping
  - 16: `sync`
  - 32: read-only remounts
  - 64: process signalling
  - 128: reboot/power-off
  - 256: nicing of all RT tasks

If the system is operational as far as having a working `root` shell, you can also invoke a magic SysRq function by writing its letter to `/proc/sysrq-trigger`; *e.g.*

```
echo s > /proc/sysrq-trigger
```

will perform an emergency `sync`.

This is all detailed in the [kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/sysrq.html).

Comment: This is a nice answer; however, what about non-standard keyboards that don't have either a 'SysRq' or 'Print Screen' key? What would happen if I were to unplug a keyboard that does have a SysRq key and plug in one that doesn't? Ref. new question I have asked [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/682965/257802).

Comment: Info on how to view the output of Alt-SysRq-Space can be found [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1814741/capture-output-of-alt-sysrq-command-input-via-true-linux-console).