# How to find out which key is the Sysrq

Tags: ubuntu, magic-sysrq

My Ubuntu 18.04 -whole system- freezes regurlary. It is a Dell Latitude 3510.

- I tried the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> (5mp)+<kbd>r</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> (2 mp delay between keystrokes) and the same with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd> at the start.
- Also tried this two while holding down the <kbd>Alt</kbd> constantly.
- My `sysrq` is enabled, `cat proc/sys/kernel/sysrq` showed a value `176` - what ever that means.
- The only way to shut it down is to take out the integrated battery from the inside of the laptop.

Is there a way to find out which key "hides" my <kbd>SysRq</kbd>?

Comment: What's the laptop exactly? AFAIK the "magic combo" depends on the manufacturer, might change between models. Also what's "2 mp delay"?

Comment: If there is no key that says `SysRq`, then usually it's the `PrtSc` key.

Comment: For the meaning of `176` check [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/211208/233201). Mine shows the same and it seems to stand for 128+32+16, which means the available functions are "reboot/power-off" (128), "read-only remounts" (32), and "sync" (16).

Answer (score 0):

The magic <kbd>SysRq</kbd> key is enabled when `cat proc/sys/kernel/sysrq` shows 1.

Use `sudo sysctl kernel.sysrq=1` for the current session or set `sysrq_always_enabled=1` as a kernel parameter to make the setting persist after a reboot.

The <kbd>PrtSc</kbd> is generally also the <kbd>SysRq</kbd> key. Just use <kbd>Alt</kbd> with <kbd>PrtSc</kbd> as normal. You can also try using <kbd>AltGr</kbd> in place of <kbd>Alt</kbd>.

See the troubleshooting part of [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Keyboard_shortcuts#Kernel_(SysRq)) archwiki section for more troubleshooting tips if this does not work.

Comment: What if there is neither a SysRq nor a PrtSc key on my keyboard? :( Using a Logitech MX Keys Mechanical (no, the Snipping Tool key does not work).