# How can I map a specific keyboard key to be SysRq?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, magic-sysrq

I am using Parabola GNU/Linux (Arch variant) on a MacBook Pro laptop. I would like to configure/enable the SysRq key, since I am experiencing fairly frequent system freezes, which are forcing me currently to have to hard-reboot the system. I have checked `/proc/config.gz` and it seems the SysRq key is enabled in the kernel config:

```
CONFIG_MAGIC_SYSRQ=y
```

So, my questions are as follows:

a) How can I verify what (if any) key is currently mapped to SysRq?

b) I would like to remap the Apple 'Command' key to SysRq (since I don't believe it is currently being used). How can I do that?

**Edit:**

Referring to the answer given [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/211208/257802), the contents of `/proc/sys/kernel/sysrq' is as follows:

```
$ cat /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq
0
```

this seems to indicate that the SysRq key is disabled (despite apparently being enabled in the kernel config) - why is that? (note that I don't believe that linked answer addresses part a) of my question).

Comment: I think your first question is answered in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/211199/how-to-discover-whether-magic-sysrq-key-is-enabled-and-what-keys-invoke-it?rq=1

Comment: Remapping is explained here: https://superuser.com/questions/876537/remapping-sysrq-in-linux

Comment: Thanks for your replies - I will check those out

Comment: @Henriksupportsthecommunity as far as I can see, the answer there doesn't seem to address the question of how to find out what keyboard key (if any) is currently mapped to SysRq. The Macbook Pro keyboard doesn't include either a 'SysRq' or 'Print Screen' key. I will add the contents of `/proc/sys/kernel/sysrq' to my question.